Fokker-Planck equation for colored noise Langevin equation
I was wondering if there is a way to derive the Fokker-Planck equation for Langevin equation with a general colored noise:
$$m \ddot{x} = -\frac{\partial V(x)}{\partial x} - \gamma \dot{x} + F(t)$$
with $\langle F(t) F(t') \rangle=\chi(t-t')$, some arbitrary (well-behaved) function.
I found this post Relation between Langevin and Fokker-Planck for exponentially correlated noise, which was incredibly useful. However, the trick of writing the evolution of the exponentially correlated noise appears to only work when the correlation is exponential (the OU process governing the dynamics of the noise generates exponential correlations). I figure that it may be possible to use a similar technique but using a different stochastic process rather than an OU process to generate the desired correlation. However, this seems like it would probably bring me back to the original problem. Is there a know alternative (non-perturbative) approach or a way to find such an appropriate auxiliary stochastic process for the dynamics of the noise?

At some point in your solution, you will need to either identify $\chi(t-t')$ or identify how it behaves under certain limits (e.g., $t\gg t'$, $t\ll t'$, $t-t'\gg\tau_c$, etc). It might be easiest to see the derivation if you let $V=0$ or let $m=0$ (which I don't think there's supposed to be the $m$ attached to the $\dot{x}$ term, is there?)

@KyleKanos Whether $m\gamma\dot{x}$ needs the $m$ from $m\ddot{x}$ depends on how $\gamma$ is defined. I've seen both conventions. In this one, $[\gamma]=\mathsf{T}^{-1}$.

@KyleKanos, I was considering the case where $\chi(t-t') \propto - \frac{1}{\sinh^2(t-t')}$. I was ideally hoping to find a closed form solution if possible rather than considering limiting behaviour. Also, my bad, indeed the $m$ was a typo. I was ultimately looking to analyse the underdamped equation but if neglecting the inertial term provides a stepping stone to the full solution I would be happy to see how to proceed in the overdamped case with a free particle.

@J.G. Interesting to know that sometimes the $m$ is included as a prefactor of the damping term, I hadn't seen that before.

A not so useful trick (in most complex cases) is to write down your kernel as an infinite sum of exponentially correlated noise (you would get the coefficient in front of every exponential from a laplace transform). Your noise correlation would then be expressed as the sum of exponentially correlated noise. You could then rewrite your unique equation with complex correlated noise to a matrix equation with an infinite number of auxiliary variable. You would then have to solve an infinite dimensional multivariate ornstein uhlenbeck process. Which is sometime easy. At least you know the formal..

... solution (see van kampen book, the section about multivariate ornstein uhlenbeck). In the case of a unique exponentially correlated noise. This is what is done in your link. The process of going from a non markovian (gaussian correlated) equation to an infinite amount of markovian equation is called markovianization and can take many form (I think Mori was the one who introduced it from a infinite regression of fraction but don't cite me on that)...

As an example see the equivalence between eqs 1,2,3 and eqs 5,6,7,8 in https://arxiv.org/pdf/2207.08218 . Note that the equivalence does not hold at the level of the entropy production, I could go on and on  on the subject it's fascinating. But maybe for an other answer (not a lengthy comment this time :) ) if you wish. In any case, this method might not be appropriate since it is hard to find the right expansion of the kernel in terms of exponential. Now: eq 15 with p = 0 https://arxiv.org/abs/2011.09771 is formally what you are looking for. An exact (without laplace transform) solution is..

... in general to complicated to obtain. Note that the underdamped solution is also dealt with below in the case of an harmonic oscillator.

AAAH, MY BAD. I didn't read well your post. I thought that the damping term was including $\chi(t)$ as a convolution in order for the system to respect the fluctuation dissipation of second kind. As it is written now, your equation does not describe an equilibrium system. It would not change tooooo much the analysis done in the last article (but a lot the one done in the first article) since the probabilities would still be gaussian. But this would have to be taken into account..
